# Testing Benford's law using Chi Squared

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am attempting to show that the uniform distribution is NOT a good distribution to use when determining the distribution of leading significant digit for number. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy import special

n = 1500
fact_series = scipy.special.factorial(np.arange(n), exact = True)
first_digit = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    first_digit[i] = int(str(fact_series[i])[0])    

n_tmp, bins, patches = plt.hist(first_digit, bins = 9, density = True)

freq_obs = n_tmp
stats.chisquare(n_tmp) # chisquare defaults values as being equally likely
```

This produces output:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.5031000000000001, pvalue=0.9998634598614591)
```

which does not seem correct as we should be rejecting the null hypothesis instead of fail to reject. I presume this has to do with what I am feeding `stats.chisquare` which is the frequencies observed from the generated data: `array([0.3285, 0.19125, 0.13725, 0.12225, 0.084, 0.093, 0.06, 0.05775, 0.051])`. I presume this is what should be plugged into the function, per the documentation:

```
f_obs : array_like
Observed frequencies in each category.
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supplying proportions instead of counts, so your statistic will be much smaller than it should be.

The usual statistic is based on counts, not observed proportions.